# Prevent csrf attack in modx formit

Tags: csrf, modx, modx-revolution, formit

Currently I am using FormIt to send emails in Modx. But how can I prevent csrf attacks? I found that we can prevent csrf attacks by adding a token to our form.
How can I apply this to Formit?

```
[[!FormIt?  
    &fsFormTopic=`contact` 
    &submitVar=`contact` 
    &hooks=`FormSave,ShootCC_contact,redirect`
    &emailTpl=`my_email_tpl`
    &emailTo=`example@gmail.com`
    &redirectTo=`[[!switch?  
        &get=`[[+ck]]`
        &c1=`eng`
        &do1=`6`
        &c2=`trad`
        &do2=`1766`
        &c3=`simp`
        &do3=`1786`
        &default=`6`
    ]]`
]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prehook to validate the form before submission, take a peek here:

[Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

You can probably generate a CSRF token by modifying Modx's session handling - keep in mind that modx sessions last a week by default, so you will also want to add some kind of timeout to your CSRF tokens.